# Unable to have multiple Subject listeners subscribed simultaneously in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

In Angular, I have two components that are listening to an RXJS Subject in a service. Both components are concurrently loaded, each in a separate [tab](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview).

My problem is that when the observable/subject is updated, only one of the event listeners get triggered. The one that does get triggered works as intended.

The subscriber, called in ngOnInit() (Its the same for both).

```
  connectClear(){
this.sideBarService.clearEventChange
  .subscribe((clearEvent)=> {
    if(clearEvent)
    {
      if(this.previousSelected !== null){
        this.previousSelected.classList.remove('selected')
        for(let i=0;i<this.previousSelected.cells.length;i++){
          this.previousSelected.cells[i].classList.remove('selection')
        }
  
        this.previousSelected = null
      }
      
    }
  })}
```

The service:

```
  clearEvent:boolean
  clearEventChange:Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>()

  setClear(clearEvent:boolean){
    this.clearEventChange.next(clearEvent)
  }

  constructor()  {
    this.clearEventChange.subscribe((value) => {
      this.clearEvent = value
    });
        
  }
```

One idea that I'll try is to lazy load the tabs, so that only one component is loaded at a time, and then unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy, that way only one subscriber is connected at a time. That said, I am still curious if there is a way to connect multiple subscribers at once, or if I am just doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you using the same instance of the service ?? How is it annotated?? is it available in root? Is it mentioned in `providers` section in multiple modules/components???

Comment: do `this.sideBarService.clearEventChange.pipe(tap(v=>console.log("triggered",v))
  .subscribe` and see  if this shows twice

Comment: So it is available in the root, but instantiated/declared in each of their constructors. It is not in the providers (I'm guessing it should be?)

For the code I get an error that says it cannot find the name tap.

Comment: Did you added `tap` like I told you to do? what are the results?

Comment: As i mentioned right above, I get an error that tap isn't recognized as a function.

Comment: import it. it is rx operator just like any of other oprators.

Comment: hmm after importing tap it didn't quite seem to work. I put it before the connectClear() call, then after and then in place of it and I didn't see it in the console at all.

Comment: That means, that emiter is not emitting any values, or there was an error up in the chain and subscription is cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you run *setClear()* before the method *connectClear()* of the first component is initializated.

Check this:

1. Make sure you are using the same service (as singleton).
   In order to do that, in the service decorator:

```
@injectable({ provideIn:'root})
```

2. Change the operator **Subject** for **BehaviorSubject**:
   (remember to import BehaviorSubject instead import Subject).

```
clearEventChange:Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

It will trigger a true value (and hold the value until next activation of *setClear()*).

If everything is good, both subscribers should activate.

Comment: A behavior subject just initializes with the boolean true. If you want to listen to events fired before subscribing to the subject, try a ReplaySubject. It'll send a specified amount of previous triggers. Mostly one is enough so maybe `new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1)` will do. This of course will only help if the 2nd subscription really only comes after the next() is fired. @Preston it's usually not a bad idea to unsubscribe in the onDestroy anyways.